# The capabilities of search engines

Tags: computer-science

I have an assignment in faculty in data storage and retrieval course. the assignment is to search for applied capabilities in Google,Yahoo and Bing. i searched about it and didn't get any result, so does anyone know what is this or how can i get an answer?

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you are looking for? Are you trying to find out what technologies have been used for google, yahoo, bing?

Comment: Honestly i don't know she asked for this assignment literally as i mentioned above (search for applied capabilities in google...) all i know is that the capabilities help the user to determine which items he want and what he doesn't by his eyes i guess. i try to search about them but i got nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use search engines more effectively to find things. You can find some answers to your question in [this paper](http://www.ijarcst.com/doc/vol2-issue3/ver.2/sridhar_n.pdf) from Sridhar, Renuka, Nirmala  and Swarna.

Edit: Also, you can try to do search with a [scholar.google](https://scholar.google.com/) the next time for more academic answers.

Comment: File not found. i searched about it in scholar but i got nothing but thank you

Comment: Link is corrected.